# Python pytube Playlist is null when the youtube playlist has a chinese name

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

When using *pl = Playlist(link)*,

**Playlist with chinese name: Not OK - pl is empty**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSUaNt76UAM&list=RDHSUaNt76UAM

Playlist works:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58PpYacL-VQ&list=UUd6MoB9NC6uYN2grvUNT-Zg

Is it because of coding issue? But pytube works fine when downloading a video with chinese name.

Comment: It would be more appropriate to file a bug request with the pytube developers (e.g., on github) if you think there is a problem with their package.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the library, but there is [a fix](https://github.com/nficano/pytube/pull/673) for that now but it's not merged yet...

This is a temporary workaround to fix it :

- deleted the old version of the library with pip:

```
pip uninstall pytube3
```

And install it from the fork:

```
 pip install git+https://github.com/Maelstrom6/pytube3.git
```

Hope this will help.....

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
from pytube import Playlist
playlist = Playlist(youtube video link)
print('Number of videos in playlist: %s' % len(playlist.video_urls))
for video_url in playlist.video_urls:
    print(video_url)
```

hope this helps you!